# How to process onClick and not href <a>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm using a jquery plugin and for it to work properly I have to have my book now button (styled to look like a button) be inside an anchor tag. My react component looks like this:

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
        showModal: false,
    };
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.exitModal = this.exitModal.bind(this);
}


openModal(){
    console.log('hello');
    this.setState(()=> ({showModal: true}));
    return false;
}

exitModal(){
    this.setState(()=> ({showModal: false}));
}

render(){
    return (
        ...

            <li>
                <a id="navbar-book" href="#" onClick={this.openModal} className="book-button"><span>Book Now</span></a>
            </li>
        ...
             <BookModal 
                showModal={this.state.showModal}
                exitModal={this.exitModal}
            />  

    )
}
```

};

I don't want to have an href but if I don't have it my dropotron plugin won't work on it. I've already tried to return false from the function in hopes that href wouldn't run. All I need it to do is run the modal.

Comment: You can't add onClick functions to html through js-added HTML as far as I know. I bumped into this some years back (about 5-6 years back) and that's what I concluded from it. If you want it to work, use javascript-side bindings, not html-side.

Comment: Did you tried href="javascript:void(0)"?

Comment: href="javascript:void(0)" did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a button like this:

```
<button onClick={this.openModal}>Book Now</button>
```

But if you really must use a link you must use **preventDefault** on the click event like this:

```
openModal(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(()=> ({showModal: true}));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed it to a button and restructured my layout to work around it. I had tried the prevent default method before but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing it with a button?

```
<button onClick={this.openModal}>Book Now</button>
```